# Lock screen doesn't remember username

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, login

On Windows Server 2008 R2, when I lock the machine, when I return, the Logon Screen screen doesn't remember my username:

[image: Windows Server 2008 R2]

I definitely still have a session, because when I log back in, it remembers the state for everything.

This is different that the way locking is handled in most other servers where the username is pre-filled, like this example in 2012:

[image: Windows Server 2012 R2]

Where can I go to change this setting?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a local or domain group policy. Run gpedit.msc on the machine in question and expand the following policy tree:

> Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name

Set that to "Disabled" and see if that does it. You can run `gpupdate /force` from the command prompt to apply the policy change right away.

Also, or instead, check the same setting on any GPOs at the domain level that would apply to the server in question.

Comment: + for the right place to look even though [it didn't seem to be the issue in my case](http://i.imgur.com/lgUbgrm.png)

Comment: Did you check the domain GPOs also? When I started writing I didn't realize at first that you were on a domain.

Comment: I can't edit this field on my computer. I believe I should go to our sys admin to make this change.